# ASP.Net Core web app defaults to displaying the currency in dollars after deploying to Azure App service, how can I change the default currency?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

Using ToString("C") locally displays the currency in GBP.  After deploying to Azure Application Service it defaults to dollars.  Using .Net 7.

In the Startup.cs I have the following set.  What am I missing?

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB", "en-GB");
            options.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en-GB") };
        });
```

Comment: What is the `.NET core` version you are using?

Comment: Could you please share your code,where you are displaying the currency?

Comment: @Harshitha I'm using .net 7.  Regarding the code it's a decimal property using the above ToString("C")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To workaround this issue you can add the following argument to the `ToString()` method.

```
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")
```

For example

```
<td>@order.UnitPrice.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"))</td>
```

Now, when I deploy the web app to Azure it displays currency values with the GBP symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't waste any more time on this issue, after my testing I found the root cause of the problem, nothing to do with your code.

I recreated the virtual machine specifically for testing because I found that the root cause was that the browser didn't have the language you needed.

Please check out the gif below for my demo in more than a minute.

[image]

To briefly illustrate, my asp.net core program is the same as yours, and after direct deployment, it is found that it is inconsistent with the local running results.  Then I was able to reproduce this issue locally using a brand new browser, so at the time I thought the issue had nothing to do with Azure app service.

After digging deeper, I found that the problem was browser-related, and the most incredible thing is that if I remove the installed language, such as the Chinese in my picture, the browser will continue to work normally.

To sum up, this problem is only related to browsers, if this webapp wants to be localized for users in other countries, don't worry, the browser will normally include that language.

Comment: Interesting, I will take a look in the morning and update with feedback.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm using Edge and I've removed all preferred languages except English (United Kingdom, Oxford English Dictionary Spelling) and using ToString("C") still results in the dollar symbol appearing.

Comment: @WooHoo Please try another browser such as Google. If the same problem recurs, please continue to follow my test steps to try.

Comment: @WooHoo The purpose of changing the browser is just to prove that the problem is related to the browser.

Comment: I've did try Chrome, also removed Englush (US) so both Edge and Chrome are running using English (United Kingdom).  So if this setting has an impact on the currency I would expect to see a £ symbol.  Unless I've missed something, very strange.

Comment: @WooHoo This problem can also be reproduced when I run it locally in vs, so I don't think this is related to Azure Web App.

Comment: When I run the app locally using VS/Edge ToString("C") displays as a pound.  If I open another tab in the same instance of Edge and try https://dotnetfiddle.net/HL2oYA the value is displayed with a dollar symbol.  If it was a browser setting I would expect the .net fiddle code to display a £ symbol.  I'm confused :)